# Object declaration in a loop for different ML models

Tags: python, loops

Can anyone help me out, how can I perform the following task? I am getting an error
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

```
models = ['LogisticRegression','RandomForestClassifier','KNeighborsClassifier' ,'DecisionTreeClassifier','SVC']
acc = {}
for model in models:
  m = model()
  m.fit(X_train_t_scaled, y_train_t)
  y_pred = m.predict(X_val_t_scaled)
  acc[model] = accuracy_score(y_val_t, y_pred)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor
models = [RandomForestRegressor]
for model in models:
    ...
```

Don't forget to

```
pip install sklearn
```